# How to make side bar to stick and not disappear on scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

okay as you can see in the above image there is a side bar which contains images for social networking sites. on scrolling it doesn't disappear..... 
[link to the image website](https://www.thesoftwareguy.in/)

SO i was wondering how does it happen and if i want to make that side bar to stick to bottom left corner how do i do that...

Comment: You are looking for the css attribute `position: fixed;`, take a look [here](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/06/microtut-how-css-position-works/demo.html).

Comment: Well, they use a combination of Javascript and CSS. What have you tried? Please review the help section on [what kind of questions to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and how to create a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Give the sidebar element a `position: fixed`. This would allow you to control its location relative to the browser window. To place it at the bottom left, simply give it `left: 0; bottom: 0`.

Here's an example:

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
This is the sidebar
</div>

<div id="content">
This is just a really long div to allow you to scroll and see the effect
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent element of your side bar `position: fixed`, you can then use the `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` properties to position your sidebar.

`Position: fixed` means the element will be pinned on the browser window.

`Position: absolute` means the element will be pinned on the page layout.